# Why i cant add element with JQuery $()?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
$( "<p>This is a new paragraph</p>" );
```

And it does not show in the page
Why?

Comment: It's only creating the element, not adding it to the DOM.

Comment: Hi, you can learn jquery here https://jquery.com/

Answer (score 3):

That code only creates the new `p` element but does not insert it in the page. You need to append it to the rest of the DOM. You can use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```
$("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>").appendTo("body");
```

Or [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
var p = $("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");
$("body").append(p);
```

Take a look also at [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) methods.

The difference between `append` and `prepend` is that the former adds the new element as the last child of the selector while the latter adds it as the first child.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that to element in the html in order to see it. Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
paragraph = $( "<p>This is a new paragraph</p>" );
$('[your-destination]').append( paragraph );
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements

Comment: here says that i can do without append

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream Yes, it says you can create elements like this. But just think how will an element show in the html if we don't mention where to show it.

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream if you read further you'll realize how it functions. > "When you create a new element, it is not immediately added to the page. There are several ways to add an element to the page once it's been created."

Comment: maybe...ok,we have deal with it